# Exceptional Divisor of Node Blow-Up is Two Smooth Reduced Points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is [Vakil 29.3 D](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf), self-study.

We are to show that if $X$ is a variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ with a node at point $p$, that the blow-up of $X$ at $p$ gives a morphism

$$\beta: \tilde{X} \to X$$

such that the exceptional divisor $\beta^{-1}(p)$ consists of two smooth reduced points. I am not sure what $\tilde{X}$ is here, but I assume it is the proper transform.

We have defined a node to be a closed point $p \in X$ such that $\widehat{\mathcal O}_{X, p} \cong k[[x,y]]/(xy)$ as topological rings, where the completion is of course taken $\mathfrak m_{X, p}$-adically.

I don't really see how to parse this. The given hint says to use the fact that completion is flat, I assume to conclude that the natural map $\mathcal O_{X, p} \to \widehat{\mathcal O}_{X, p}$ is flat. I assume then that we are supposed to use this to conclude that the proper transform map

$$\beta: \tilde{X} \to X$$

is then flat. Then, we are supposed to use 24.2 P a), I think to conclude that

$$\operatorname{Bl}_pX \times_X \tilde{X} \cong \operatorname{Bl}_{\beta^{-1}(p)}\tilde{X}$$

and somehow combine this information to turn this into a calculation on $\widehat{\mathcal O}_{X, p} \cong k[[x,y]]/(xy)$. What calculation? And is everything I have said thus far correct?

Comment: With Vakil's definition, is it the case that locally at $p$, $X$ is one-dimensional?

Comment: @mathmath I wondered that myself. I assume the answer is yes because the discussion just prior to this talks about classifying singularities for curves.

Comment: Since he only defines a node if $\widehat{\mathcal O}_{X, p} \cong k[[x,y]]/(xy)$ is one-dimensional, then so is $\mathcal O_{X, p}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how this concludes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's get one thing out of the way at the start: $\tilde{X}$ is the blowup of $X$ at $p$, which is defined intrinsically as the relative proj of $\bigoplus\mathcal{I}_p^n$. If $X$ is embedded as a closed subvariety of some larger variety $Y$, then $\tilde{X}$ is exactly the proper transform of $X$ under the blowup of $Y$ at $p$ - we won't really use that during the reduction here, but it could be useful at the end depending on how you decide to attack the calculation with $k[[x,y]]/(xy)$ (the proof of this statement is probably somewhere in the chapter on blowups). Note that the blowup map is essentially never flat, so you're barking up the wrong tree there.

---

Now on to the main problem. Consider the sequence of maps $$\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(p) \to \operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}\to \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p} \to X.$$ We can base change by $\beta:\widetilde{X}=Bl_p X\to X$ to get the following diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\widetilde{X}\times_X \operatorname{Spec} \kappa(p)  @>>> \widetilde{X}\times_X\operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}} @>>> \widetilde{X}\times_X\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p} @>>> \widetilde{X}\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VV{\beta}V\\
\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(p) @>>> \operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}} @>>> \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p} @>>> X
\end{CD}
$$

Let's make some observations.
First, $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p} \to X$ is flat, because it's the identity on stalks.
Next, $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\to \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}$ is flat because completion is flat, so $\operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}} \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is flat and therefore $\operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}} \to X$ is flat.
By exercise 24.2.P(a), this means that $$\widetilde{X}\times_X\operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}\cong  Bl_{p\times_X \operatorname{Spec}\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}} \operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}.$$
Finally, the top left corner is the fiber over $p$ in each of the other entries in the top row, so the fiber of $\beta:\widetilde{X}\to X$ over $p$ can be computed by looking at the fiber of $Bl_{p\times_X \operatorname{Spec}\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}} \operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}\to \operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}$ over the closed point.

From here, you have some options: you can calculate the blowup of $(x,y)\subset k[[x,y]]/(xy)$ as Proj of $(k[[x,y]]/(xy))[t,u]/(xt-yu)$ with $x,y$ in degree zero and $t,u$ in degree one, or you can pull a fast one. We can replace $X$ with $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy)$ while keeping $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}$ the same, so the fiber over the node in general is the same as the fiber over the node in $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy)$. Both of these calculations should be approachable for you - a generalized version of the second computation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3430671/blow-up-strict-transform-and-tangent-cone-gathmann-notes-exercise-9-22), and it's very similar to what you'd need to do .

Comment: So essentially what should happen after I compute this blowup is that I will see the closed point in the Spec of the completion has two distinct preimages, correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time out to write that answer!